# How get all selected values (not empty) for all selects in Prototype $$()?

Tags: javascript, html, select, prototypejs

How get all selected values (not empty) for all selects in document using Prototype dollar dollar function `$$()` ?

Thanks,
Celso

Comment: How do you define "empty"? The option does or doesn't have a `value`? The option does or doesn't have text content? It would be helpful if you posted your HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what your definition of *"empty"* is.

This needs to be known because most browsers will look at the `value` attribute as well as the text content of the option.

Assuming that there *is* a `value` attribute that has been set to an empty string, or there's no value and no text content, then you could do this:

```
var result = $$('select').invoke('getValue').without('');
```

Answer (score -1):

One reason I switched to jQuery is that it is a lot easier to handle these situations.

You may need do it the hard way in Prototype:

```
$$('...').each(function(element) {
    if(element.innerHTML=='') {
        // your operation
    }

})
```